# How to manage page navigation in ajax based ASP.NET MVC web applications

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, navigation

When we don't use ajax, browser's backward and forward arrows provide navigation to previous (and next) pages. Although when we use ajax to retrieve information (to have a single page application), we loose previous pages and browser does not know anything about the history of navigation.

What is the best solution for managing the history of previous pages when we use ajax specially in ASP.NET MVC web applications context.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The history api of html5 is the key. See:
https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/